# MongoDB collection update with $set and aggregate

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo, updates

I need to change the type of `timestamp_ms` filed from `string` to `double` and create `FixedDate` field which is based on this new `timestamp_ms` field. Than, change timestamp info into ISO date in `NewDate` field.

I used this code:

```
collection.update({
    "FixedDate": {"$exists": False}
},[{
    "$set":
        {"FixedDate":
            {"$convert":
                {"input": "$timestamp_ms",
                "to": "double"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {"$set":
        {"NewDate":
                {"$toDate": "$FixedDate"
                }
            }
    }
], multi=True)
```

It gives this error message:

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

My data looks like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea920d326051990a7f337'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:21:07 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638867739'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea920d326051990a7f339'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:21:08 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638868310'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea972d326051c5c05bc11'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:30 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638950799'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea974d326051c5c05bc16'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638952160'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5afea974d326051c5c05bc17'), 'created_at': 'Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018', 'timestamp_ms': '1526638952841'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of issues, the first is you are not using the latest driver for 4.2 (it's still in beta so if you just did pip upgrade you would still be on 3.8 and you need 3.9).  Install the latest with 
    `python -m pip install https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/archive/3.9.0b1.tar.gz`
at least until it's GA.

Second, you should use `update_one` or `update_many` rather than `update` with `multi` flag.

Trying your code with latest version, this works:

```
collection.update_many(
   {"FixedDate": {"$exists": False}},
   [{"$set":{
      "FixedDate":{"$toDouble":"$timestamp_ms"}
  }},
  {"$set":{
      "NewDate": {"$toDate": "$FixedDate"}
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your problem with aggregation framework,

```
let query = [
    {
        $match: {
            "FixedDate": { "$exists": false }
        }
    }, {
        $addFields: {
            "FixedDate":
                {
                    "$convert":
                        {
                            "input": "$timestamp_ms",
                            "to": "double"
                        }
                },

        },
    }, {
        $addFields: {
            "NewDate":
                {
                    "$toDate": "$FixedDate"
                }
        }
    }]
```

`db.collection.aggregate(query)`

here you need to use two times [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html)

**Result**

```
/* 1 createdAt:18/05/2018, 15:51:20*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afea920d326051990a7f337"),
    "created_at" : "Fri May 18 10:21:07 +0000 2018",
    "timestamp_ms" : "1526638867739",
    "FixedDate" : 1526638867739,
    "NewDate" : ISODate("2018-05-18T15:51:07.739+05:30")
},

/* 2 createdAt:18/05/2018, 15:51:20*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afea920d326051990a7f339"),
    "created_at" : "Fri May 18 10:21:08 +0000 2018",
    "timestamp_ms" : "1526638868310",
    "FixedDate" : 1526638868310,
    "NewDate" : ISODate("2018-05-18T15:51:08.310+05:30")
},

/* 3 createdAt:18/05/2018, 15:52:42*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afea972d326051c5c05bc11"),
    "created_at" : "Fri May 18 10:22:30 +0000 2018",
    "timestamp_ms" : "1526638950799",
    "FixedDate" : 1526638950799,
    "NewDate" : ISODate("2018-05-18T15:52:30.799+05:30")
},

/* 4 createdAt:18/05/2018, 15:52:44*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afea974d326051c5c05bc16"),
    "created_at" : "Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018",
    "timestamp_ms" : "1526638952160",
    "FixedDate" : 1526638952160,
    "NewDate" : ISODate("2018-05-18T15:52:32.160+05:30")
},

/* 5 createdAt:18/05/2018, 15:52:44*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5afea974d326051c5c05bc17"),
    "created_at" : "Fri May 18 10:22:32 +0000 2018",
    "timestamp_ms" : "1526638952841",
    "FixedDate" : 1526638952841,
    "NewDate" : ISODate("2018-05-18T15:52:32.841+05:30")
}
```

Comment: $set is an alias for $addFields so your answer is not correct.